# Change value of textarea on dropdown select

Tags: javascript, ajax, tinymce, textarea, drop-down-menu

Ignore the previous question - this is the only bit I don't understand now, everything else works:

**UPDATE: ALMOST WORKING**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#fileSelect").click(function(){
     var myString = <?php
      $array = array('homeText.txt', 'anotherText.txt' /*ETC*/);
      $file = $array[/*JS SELECTED INDEX*/];
      $path = '../txt/'.$file;
      include $path;
      ?>
        tinyMCE.execCommand('mceReplaceContent',false,myString);
 });
});
```

**QUESTION: How would I pass the index of the selected item in the dropdown into that php code (from the jquery), so that I could call the appropriate item in the array to return the right file.**

Comment: JavaScript is sandboxed, so you cannot read nor write files from there.

Comment: I don't want to - I want to run some php when a js event is called

Comment: @Shi: He can if the file is accessible via some web server.

Comment: Well, yes. But that's transparent for a script then. If content is fetched via HTTP, it can originate from everywhere - database, file, proxied stream or whatever. Thus, the emphasis on _file_ was a bit irritating.

Comment: I wasn't sure (given the accepted answer) if you were still having issues, so I added the jQuery version below my prior code...your problem in the above code is that the PHP runs before the JS...so you need to take the PHP out and form it as a web service...then the JS will send the selection value to that service, and the service will echo the file contents...that you then pop into the textarea

Comment: Hi - thanks I got a little bit of help from the folks in the javascript chat - but they said use ajax so I tried out your code in combo with the jquery stuff and it works perfectly... thanks very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use AJAX to read in the files.
You'll add an 'onchange' function to the dropdown, so that each time the user changes it, the ajax function will fire (retrieving the file contents) and insert that text into the textarea.

Here is a similar situation that used PHP in the background to generate the text...but you can modify that so that it just calls the appropriate file based on the selection (or, if you prefer, make a single PHP file that echoes the right text based on some GET variable [or POST if you like])

[Populating dropdown - PHP Ajax MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5332999/populating-dropdown-php-ajax-mysql/5334008#5334008)

you'd also change the destination of the data from the dropdown to your textarea. So here's some code...it uses the hypothetical getMyText.php (passing it the 'file' variable) and expects text back, which it will then place in the textarea.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<script>
function changeText(choice){
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
          {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          }
        else
          {// code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
            var res=xmlhttp.responseText;
            document.getElementById("myText").innerHTML=res;
            }
          }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","getMyText.php?file="+choice,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        }
</script>

<select onChange="changeText(this.value)">
<option value="opt1">Option1</option>
<option value="opt2">Option2</option>
</select>
<textarea id="myText"></textarea>

</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: Using jQuery

the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
<script>
function changeText(choice){
$.get('so_getfile.php?file='+choice, function(data) {
  $('#myText').html(data);
});
        }
</script>

<select onChange="changeText(this.value)">
<option></option>
<option value="1">Option1</option>
<option value="2">Option2</option>
</select>
<textarea id="myText"></textarea>

</body>
</html>
```

the PHP web service:

```
<?php
$array = array('file1.txt', 'file2.txt');
$file = $array[$_GET['file']-1];
$text = fopen($file,'r');
if ($text) {
    while (($buffer = fgets($text, 4096)) !== false) {
        echo $buffer;
    }
    if (!feof($text)) {
        echo "Error: unexpected fgets() fail\n";
    }
    fclose($text);
}
?>
```

Comment: it's Async Javascript And XML (it's a misnomer though, any response is okay)...I'll add some sample code here in a moment

Comment: to cwallenpoole's framework comments, if you use a framework like jQuery, that function turns into something like `$.ajax(file)`...much neater

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the 'change' event of the select. Because events can be very inconsistent between different browsers, you will most likely want a framework to help:

```
var sel = document.getElementById("selectbox1");

// if older versions of IE
// use attachEvent instead: sel.attachEvent("onchange", changeHandler);
sel.addEventListener("change", changeHandler, false);

function changeHandler(e)
{
   // your selected item can be found this way
   console.log( sel.options[sel.selectedIndex] )
   // or this way (technically there can be multiple items selected, 
   // you need to use the 0 index to get the first one.)
   sel.getSelected()[0] 
}
```

You also need to place an AJAX request in that method, so you will have to create an [XMLHttpRequest](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/). Seriously, this is something which you *REALLY* should use a framework for. But here is a possible method:

```
// if IE: var req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
// you are probably going to want to use GET to do this.
req.open("GET", "result_of_select.php?choice="+
               sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value, true);
// if you want POST, then you'll have to create the request parameter string
// and pass it to send
req.send();
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
 if(this.readyState == 2) {
  document.getElementById("my-text-field").text = req.responseText
 }
}
```