# Dropdown Bind using Ajax without page refresh

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Form Fields In PHP:

Start Date: ***_*__*_*_**

End Date : ***_*__*_*__**

Dropdown : dropdownlist

After entered the End date need to bind dropdown without page refresh and using `Ajax`. How to do this? Have to send the start and end date value to `MySql` and check condition and need to select as per the condition then Have to fill DropDown.

Comment: Have you heard of the nice search feature we have on this site? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5332999/populating-dropdown-php-ajax-mysql

Comment: I think you have to take a look on jquery( javascript library ), read about some basic events. According to your need you have to read: .focus(), .blur(), $.ajax()

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery (if not use this as psudocode):

```
$( ".startdate .enddate" ).change(function() {
    if(typeof $( ".startdate" ).val() !== "undefined" && $( ".startdate" ).val() !== "" 
    && typeof $( ".enddate" ).val() !== "undefined" && $( ".enddate" ).val() !== "" ) {
        //do optional formatting and ajax call here
        //update the dropdown using results of ajax call
    }
});
```

Basically, make an event listener for when the dates are updated, then if they are both valid, do the ajax call, then update the dropdown with the results of the ajax call.